Mean field equations in different form
Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface with volume $1$, $h$ be a continuous positive function on $M$, and $\rho$ be a real number. Consider the following nonlinear equation:
$$
\Delta_g u+\rho\left(\frac{h e^u}{\int_M h e^u}-1\right)=0 \quad \text { on } M,
$$
where $\Delta_g$ is the Beltrami-Laplace operator on $M$.
Another mean field equation can be formulated as
$$
\begin{cases}\Delta u+\rho \frac{h e^u}{\int_{\Omega} h e^u}=0 & \text { in } \Omega \\ u=0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}
$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded, smooth domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
My question is if these two equations are equivalent in some sense?
